# Resolver fazer alguma coisa!

Tags: português-brasileiro

O que significa **resolver fazer alguma coisa**?

O texto é:

> Quanta gente na loja! Parece que tudo mundo resolveu fazer compras hoje!

Está dizendo **Decidir fazer alguma coisa**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim. Confira o significado, e.g., no [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/resolver):

> 4. Decidir, determinar.

Comment: Então terminar fazer alguma coisa é diferente com finalizar fazer alguma coisa?

Comment: @Majid "*Terminar de fazer" é "to finish doing"; **não** se diz "finalizar fazer" ou "finalizar de fazer" (alguma coisa), mas sim "*finalizar alguma coisa". E, sim, os significados são aproximadamente iguais.